# Expression to run two geometry functions in expression builder

Tags: qgis, geometry, expression, qgis-2.14, autofields

I have feature polygons that sit within and across larger tenancy polygons, I need to transfer the tenancy reference from the tenancy polygons to the feature polygons. To do this I am using AutoFields Expression Builder to automatically fill in the feature polygons reference field as a new polygon is created.

My problem is I can either run the expression to return intersections or within, I can not work out how to do both at the same time. My current expressions are

```
geomintersects( 'NAT_CAP_Test_Tenancies',  'REFERENCE' )
```

and

```
geomwithin( 'NAT_CAP_Test_Tenancies',  'REFERENCE' )
```

is there a way to combine both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use an `if` conditional whereby if the feature is within another, the attributes are copied over otherwise it will check if the feature intersects another:

```
if(geomwithin( 'NAT_CAP_Test_Tenancies', 'REFERENCE' ) is not NULL,
geomwithin( 'NAT_CAP_Test_Tenancies', 'REFERENCE' ),
geomintersects( 'NAT_CAP_Test_Tenancies', 'REFERENCE' ))
```

Comment: @PDreyer - Most welcome, glad it helped :)